# File beat is not transferring data to logstash

Tags: java, ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Beat input is not transferring to logstash. I have provided filebeat and logstash configuration files below.

Input Test.cs file

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2015-04-02,125.03,125.56,124.19,125.32,32120700,125.32
2015-04-01,124.82,125.12,123.10,124.25,40359200,124.25
```

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
   - type: log
     enabled: true
     paths:
           -C:/ELK Stack/filebeat-8.2.0-windows-x86_64/filebeat-8.2.0-windows-x86_64/Test.csv

output.logstash:
hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

logstash.conf

```
input {
   beats {
      port => 5044
   }
}
filter {
     csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj Close"]
 }
 mutate {convert => ["High", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Open", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Low", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Close", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Volume", "float"]}
}
output {  
    stdout {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly to check the filebeat yml file as there an issue with indentation

filebeat [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html)

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/messages
    - /var/log/*.log
```

your filebeat

```
filebeat.inputs:
   - type: log
     enabled: true
     paths:
           -C:/ELK Stack/filebeat-8.2.0-windows-x86_64/filebeat-8.2.0-windows-x86_64/Test.csv

output.logstash:
hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

and for information [log input is deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log), instead use [filesream input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/8.2/filebeat-input-filestream.html)

Comment: it worked once but again same issue.

Comment: it's not transferring to logstash again ? and the files are always updated ?

Comment: my mistake. Now it's working as expected.

Comment: Hi @abhi312 can you share what solution worked for you.